# Satisfy quantities per line in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array objects with quantities. In this array I have a key that tells me the value to fill (amountToFill) and a key that tells me the value already filled (amountFilled). The idea is to indicate a quantity (amount: number = 50;) and automatically amountFilled be filled with the same value as amountToFill but always reducing the value of (amount: number = 50) as the array is filled is the amount: number = 50 be equal to 0.

If the amountFilled is > 0, we must be careful when calculating the subtraction of the total amount.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sgerpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**initial result**

```
amountArray =[{
    option:'text',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:0,
  },
  {
    option:'text1',
    amountToFill: 3,
    amountFilled:1,
  },
  {
    option:'text2',
    amountToFill: 10,
    amountFilled:0,
  },
  {
    option:'text3',
    amountToFill: 4,
    amountFilled:1,
  },
  {
    option:'text4',
    amountToFill: 4,
    amountFilled:1,
  },
  {
    option:'text5',
    amountToFill: 15,
    amountFilled:0,
  },
  {
    option:'text6',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:2,
  },
  {
    option:'text7',
    amountToFill:25,
    amountFilled:3,
  },
  {
    option:'text8',
    amountToFill: 15,
    amountFilled:0,
  },
  {
    option:'text9',
    amountToFill: 25,
    amountFilled:0,
  },
  {
    option:'text10',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:0,
  }];
```

**Desired result**

```
 amountArray1 =[{
    option:'text',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:5,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text1',
    amountToFill: 3,
    amountFilled:3,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text2',
    amountToFill: 10,
    amountFilled:10,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text3',
    amountToFill: 4,
    amountFilled:4,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text4',
    amountToFill: 4,
    amountFilled:4,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text5',
    amountToFill: 15,
    amountFilled:15,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text6',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:5,
    filled: true
  },
  {
    option:'text7',
    amountToFill:25,
    amountFilled:12,  //amount = 0
    filled: true  
  },
  {
    option:'text8',
    amountToFill: 15,
    amountFilled:0,
    filled: false 
  },
  {
    option:'text9',
    amountToFill: 25,
    amountFilled:0,
    filled: false 
  },
  {
    option:'text10',
    amountToFill: 5,
    amountFilled:0,
    filled: false 
  }];
```

Comment: I don't understand the pattern in your desired result, can you shorten it or try to explain it in a different way?

Comment: In the desired result we can see that per line of the array the amount filled is equal to the amount needed until the amount (amount = 50) is 0, that is amount = 0; For each quantity filled in, a (-) is subtracted from this value. Every time each line is filled, I intend to add a new "property to object", filled: true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const amountArray =[{ option:'text', amountToFill: 5, amountFilled:0, }, { option:'text1', amountToFill: 3, amountFilled:1, }, { option:'text2', amountToFill: 10, amountFilled:0, }, { option:'text3', amountToFill: 4, amountFilled:1, }, { option:'text4', amountToFill: 4, amountFilled:1, }, { option:'text5', amountToFill: 15, amountFilled:0, }, { option:'text6', amountToFill: 5, amountFilled:2, }, { option:'text7', amountToFill:25, amountFilled:3, }, { option:'text8', amountToFill: 15, amountFilled:0, }, { option:'text9', amountToFill: 25, amountFilled:0, }, { option:'text10', amountToFill: 5, amountFilled:0, }];
  
 let total = 50;
 const res = amountArray.map(it => {
 const subtract = it.amountToFill - it.amountFilled;
 if (total - subtract > 0) {
    total -= subtract;
  return {...it, amountFilled: it.amountToFill, filled: !!total}
 }
 else {
   const newObj = {...it, amountFilled: it.amountFilled + total, filled: !!total}
   total = 0;
   return newObj;
 }
 });
  
console.log(res);
```